# Comparing differences in values and returning a YES or NO

Tags: excel, math

I'm trying to do two things, figure out if Value1 >= 3 AND Value2 - Value1 >= 5. If this is true, then I would like a YES to appear in a specific cell in the same row as Value2. I already had it working, but I accidentilly got the code overwritten, now I have searched for solutions and attempted to fix it for hours, but I cannot seem to find what I did when it was working. Please help!

Sheet1:

[image]

Name = RandomName
Value1 = 6

Sheet2:

[image]

Name = RandomName
Value2 = 20

```
Sub Ifgreaterthan()
Dim vFind
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim Sheet1 As Range
Dim REF As Variant
Dim NEW1 As Variant
Dim REFDELNEW1 As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
```

'Define Active cell - This looks for a Unique Identifier that is the same for Value1 and Value2

```
vFind = ActiveCell
On Error Resume Next
```

'This looks for the Unique identifier in another sheet

```
With Sheet1         
   Set rFound = .UsedRange.Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), 
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

'These are the values that are based on the Unique Identifier

```
REF = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("rFound", "Sheet1!A:B", 2, 0)
NEW1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("vFind", "Sheet2!A:B", 2, 0)
REFDELNEW1 = NEW1 - REF
```

'Variables yes and no

```
x = "Yes"
y = "No"
```

'Basic calculations

```
If REF >= 3 & REFDELNEW1 >= 5 Then
  Worksheets("Sheet2").ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = x                 
  Else: Worksheets("Sheet2").ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = y
  End If
  End With
End Sub
```

I once got a No, as I was supposed to, but I managed to lose the code. I am certain the answer was there, as I use a Excel VBA track changes log, so I am certain at some point it did what it was supposed to do. I have spent hours trying to recreate the situation and I am unsure where to look or what to do at this point. I was hoping a pro might be able to spot the solution immediately. I will also be working on the code myself in the meantime.

Comment: Your initial description of the requirement seems quite straight forward and able to be done using formulas so why use a macro as such? I’m curious.

Comment: im not sure how i would do it since the RandomNames i am matching are located in different rows on each sheet, the values i need are offset by 1 and the yes/no values need to be printed with an offset of 2. it could be easier with a formula though. i still dont have a lot of experience in excel

Comment: plus i am trying to learn how to use VBA better

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a much simpler solution to my problem. Note that what ActiveCell you are using is important.

Here is the solution from the current question:

```
 Sub Greaterthan()

    Dim REF As Integer

    Dim DEF As Integer


     On Error Resume Next

     REF = ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value

      DEF = Application.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100"), 
              Application.Match(Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveCell.Address), 
              Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:B1000"), 0))

       Number = 3

      x = "Yes"

      y = "No"


           If (REF - DEF) > Number Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = x

           Else

           ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = y

       End If


 End Sub
```